# Does the ray tracing algorithm involves rasterization of image?

Tags: algorithm, gpgpu, raytracing

I am working on a ray tracing algorithm , i know that the first step is to develop camera and view plane specifications.
Now is the next step performing rasterization algorithm on image before a BVH tree is constructed so that intersection tests can be performed?

Kindly Guide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you are asking here, but in general the next step will be to select paths for your "primary rays" -- for most raytracers, that will mean one or more rays from the eye position through each pixel of the final displayed raster image. It's not rasterization *per se* but it does involve stepping through the pixels.

I'm assuming you want to write your own tracer? With a library like OpenRL you would just call a "Frame shader" which would distribute those samples for you, but othewise the simplest case would be to just loop over all rows, over all columns, and for each of those pixel locations draw a ray from the eye through the image plane and into the scene....